# Docker history on kaniko builds shows 292 years ago

Tags: docker, kaniko

I've switched from docker-in-docker builds to kaniko builds in my build pipeline, and now the docker history results are messed up:

```
IMAGE          CREATED         CREATED BY                                      SIZE  

    COMMENT
dac3a6a7061e   292 years ago   RUN printf '\n/subsystem=datasources/data-so…   1.6kB
<missing>      292 years ago   RUN printf '\n/subsystem=datasources/data-so…   1.42kB
<missing>      292 years ago   RUN $JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh --file="/op…   271kB
```

I'm building with `/kaniko/executor` without any specific flags, and displaying history with `docker history`.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Not really sure, but maybe it is related with [reproducible flag](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko#--reproducible)

Comment: @usuario I'm not setting any flags except the necessary ones (pointing out Dockerfile and build context directory)